# Java read file with scanner

Tags: java, file

I have this code that have some methods for creating a file, adding data to the file and then read the file with scanner.
My problem is that I want it to run my three methods at once but it stops
at the method number two and does not read the file with readFile() method

```
createFile();
addResponses(file);
readFile(file);
```

I can not run these three together. It does not read the file. But if I take
the other methods away like this

```
//createFile();
//addResponses(file);
readFile(file);
```

Then the read file method works.

I hope you did understand my problem. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Main {

static Formatter f;
static String sträng = " ";
static BufferedWriter output;

static File file;
static int nummer = 1;
static int counter = 0;
static private StringBuffer strBuff;
static InputStream is;
static FileWriter fw;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    createFile();
    addResponses(file);
    readFile(file);

}

public static int addResponse() {

    if (nummer == 6) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

sträng = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Numbers 1-5 to number " + nummer");

    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(sträng);

    } catch (NumberFormatException f) {
        return 6;

    }

}

public static File createFile() {

    try {
        file = new File("numbers.txt");

        f = new Formatter(file);
        f.close();

    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        System.err.println("You dont have write access to this file");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.err.println("Error opening or creating file");
        System.exit(1);

    }

    return file;
}

public static void readFile(File x) {

    try {
        x = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(x);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {

            System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        }

        in.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }

 public static void addResponses(File f) throws IOException {

    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
        output = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        int x = addResponse();
        if (nummer == 1) {

        output.write(String.format("%s%10s\n", "Rating", "    Frequency"));
        }

        while (x != -1) {
            if (x > 0 && x < 6) {
                output.write(String.format("%s%10s\n", nummer, sträng));
                nummer++;
            } else {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input only numbers between 1-5");
            }

            x = addResponse();
        }

        output.close();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after playing around with the code, I found out that in your addResponse()  method , you have added System.exit(0); so baiscally program was terminating. I've change it to return -1 and it seems to be working.

by the way, this is a very bad coding practice, each method should do stuff seperately regarless of other method. in your case everything is so integerated that is very hard to root the problem. I recommend you looking at some coding convention.

this is how addResponse() method should be working:

```
public static File createFile() {

    try {
        file = new File("numbers.txt");

        f = new Formatter(file);
        f.close();

    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        System.err.println("You dont have write access to this file");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.err.println("Error opening or creating file");
        System.exit(1);

    }

    return file;
}
```

Comment: @TapaniYrjölä haha sorry, I made a mistake, here I updated my answer

Comment: @alright dude, ignore my previous changes. this should do it. but its a very bad coding.